# Cartesian product without duplicates

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, combinations, cartesian-product

I am using a cartesian product function that given `[1], [1,2,3], [1,2,3]` returns 9 combinations:

```
[ [ 1, 1, 1 ],
  [ 1, 2, 1 ],
  [ 1, 3, 1 ],
  [ 1, 1, 2 ],
  [ 1, 2, 2 ],
  [ 1, 3, 2 ],
  [ 1, 1, 3 ],
  [ 1, 2, 3 ],
  [ 1, 3, 3 ] ]
```

But I need to remove those with the same items regardless of the order, so `[ 1, 3, 1 ]` and `[ 1, 1, 3 ]` are the same to me. The result should contain 6 items:

```
[ [ 1, 1, 1 ],
  [ 1, 2, 1 ],
  [ 1, 3, 1 ],
  [ 1, 2, 2 ],
  [ 1, 3, 2 ],
  [ 1, 3, 3 ] ]
```

I can write a function that compares all possible pairs with `_.xor`, but for larger numbers it will probably be very inefficient. Is there a good way in Javascript to do this? An efficient way to compare all possible pairs or an algorithm for cartesian product without duplicates?

Comment: It's called multisets

Comment: Why are `[[2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 3], [2, 3, 3], [3, 3, 3]]` not to be included?

Comment: @rici Those are not valid results even in a normal cartesian product. Given the input, all sets will start with `1`.

Comment: Ah, ok.  Do you want an algorithm which would work with any sets at all? Eg. `[1], [1, 2, 4], [2, 3, 4]`?

Comment: There's a way to avoid generating the duplicates in the first place, but it's complicated.

Comment: Just avoid, for example, descending order in your samples. 1,1,3 ok, 1,3,1 not. 1,2,3 ok, 1,3,2 not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sort each array of the cartesian product

```
[ 1, 2, 1 ] -> [1 , 1 , 2]
[ 1, 1, 2 ] -> [1 , 1 , 2]
```

then gather these sorted arrays into a set, that will remove the duplicates.

Of course, you can do that while constructing the cartesian product rather than afterward.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript has [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/hu/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/hu/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), however they compare objects and arrays by reference rather than by value, so you cannot take advantage of it directly. The idea is to use a key function which sorts and json encodes the items before putting it in a set.

#### pure ES5:

```js
function product(sets) {
  if (sets.length > 0) {
    var head = sets[0];
    var tail = product(sets.slice(1));
    var result = [];
    head.forEach(function(x) {
      tail.forEach(function(xs) {
        var item = xs.slice(0);
        item.unshift(x);
        result.push(item);
      });
    });
    return result;
  } else {
    return [[]];
  }
}

function myKeyFn(item) {
  return JSON.stringify(item.slice(0).sort());
}

function uniqBy(items, keyFn) {
  var hasOwn = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty, keyset = {};
  return items.filter(function(item) {
    var key = keyFn(item);
    if (hasOwn.call(keyset, key)) {
      return false;
    } else {
      keyset[key] = 1;
      return true;
    }
  });
}

function uniqProduct(sets) {
  return uniqBy(product(sets), myKeyFn);
}

function log(x) {
  console.log(x);
  var pre = document.createElement('pre');
  pre.appendChild(document.createTextNode(x));
  document.body.appendChild(pre);
}

log(uniqProduct([[1],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]).map(JSON.stringify).join("\n"));
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

#### [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#flatMap) + [modern JavaScript](http://babeljs.io/repl/):

```
// Note: This doesn't compile on current babel.io/repl due to a bug

function product(sets) {
  if (sets.length > 0) {
    const [x, ...xs] = sets;
    const products = product(xs);
    return _.flatMap(x, head => products.map(tail => [head, ...tail]));
  } else {
    return [[]];
  }
}

function uniqProduct(sets) {
  return _.uniqBy(product(sets), x => JSON.stringify(x.slice(0).sort()));
}

console.log(uniqProduct([[1],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]).map(JSON.stringify).join("\n"));
```

Answer (score -1):

JavaScript has [set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) data structure.

So store your results in a set where each element of the set is a collection of pairs of numbers from the original sets along with the number of times that number occurs.

So your result would look something like this:

```
[ 
  {1:3},
  {1:2, 2: 1},
  { 1:2, 3:1},
  { 1:1, 2:2},
  { 1:1, 2:1, 3:1},
  { 1:1, 3:2 }  ]
```

This way, you won't be able to add the object a second time to the set.